# Request Highlighting only for the final set of rows

Tags: performance, solr

In a multi-node solr installation (without SolrCloud), during a paging scenario (e.g., `start=1000`, `rows=200`), the primary node asks for 1200 rows from each shard. If highlighting is ON, then the primary node is asking for highlighting all the 1200 results from each shard, which doesn't scale well. Is there a way to break the shard query in two steps e.g. ask for the 1200 rows and after sorting the 1200 responses from each shard and finding final rows to return (1001 to 1200) , issue another query to shards for asking highlighted response for the relevant docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that Solr behavior has changed between my old version and 6.6. Although, this seems like a bug to me after the initial investigation.

I found that if i have specified `fl=*` in the query then it is doing the right thing (a 2 pass process as it used to do in solr 4.5). However, my queries have `fl=id+score` , in which case, the shards are asked for highlighting all the results on the first request (and there is no second request).

The `fl=* query` is (in my sample case) finishing in 100 msec while same query with `fl=id+score` finishes in 1200 msec.